# Scrapy redirecting [302 to 200] but url isn't updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to fetch redirected url from a url using Scrapy

Response status changes from 302 to 200 but still the url isn't changing.

```py
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class MySpider(Spider):

    name = 'test'

    start_urls = ['https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMilwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5waW5rdmlsbGEuY29tL2VudGVydGFpbm1lbnQvYnRzLWppbi1zaGFyZXMtYmVoaW5kLXRoZS1zY2VuZXMtb2YtdGhlLWFzdHJvbmF1dC1zdGFnZS13aXRoLWNvbGRwbGF5LWJhbmQtcGVyZm9ybXMtb24tc25sLXdpdGgtd29vdHRlby0xMjA4MjQx0gGbAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnBpbmt2aWxsYS5jb20vZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudC9idHMtamluLXNoYXJlcy1iZWhpbmQtdGhlLXNjZW5lcy1vZi10aGUtYXN0cm9uYXV0LXN0YWdlLXdpdGgtY29sZHBsYXktYmFuZC1wZXJmb3Jtcy1vbi1zbmwtd2l0aC13b290dGVvLTEyMDgyNDE_YW1w']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'url': response.url,
        }


process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {
            "format": "json",
            "overwrite": True
        }},
    'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
    'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
    'REDIRECT_ENABLED': True,
    'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7'
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

Console Output

```
2023-02-08 01:44:25 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.8.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2023-02-08 01:44:25 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 23.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023), cryptography 39.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
2023-02-08 01:44:25 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8', 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7'}
2023-02-08 01:44:25 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2023-02-08 01:44:25 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 013f29d178b8cbb6
2023-02-08 01:44:25 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-02-08 01:44:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-02-08 01:44:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-02-08 01:44:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-02-08 01:44:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-02-08 01:44:26 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-02-08 01:44:26 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-02-08 01:44:26 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMilwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5waW5rdmlsbGEuY29tL2VudGVydGFpbm1lbnQvYnRzLWppbi1zaGFyZXMtYmVoaW5kLXRoZS1zY2VuZXMtb2YtdGhlLWFzdHJvbmF1dC1zdGFnZS13aXRoLWNvbGRwbGF5LWJhbmQtcGVyZm9ybXMtb24tc25sLXdpdGgtd29vdHRlby0xMjA4MjQx0gGbAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnBpbmt2aWxsYS5jb20vZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudC9idHMtamluLXNoYXJlcy1iZWhpbmQtdGhlLXNjZW5lcy1vZi10aGUtYXN0cm9uYXV0LXN0YWdlLXdpdGgtY29sZHBsYXktYmFuZC1wZXJmb3Jtcy1vbi1zbmwtd2l0aC13b290dGVvLTEyMDgyNDE_YW1w?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en> from <GET https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMilwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5waW5rdmlsbGEuY29tL2VudGVydGFpbm1lbnQvYnRzLWppbi1zaGFyZXMtYmVoaW5kLXRoZS1zY2VuZXMtb2YtdGhlLWFzdHJvbmF1dC1zdGFnZS13aXRoLWNvbGRwbGF5LWJhbmQtcGVyZm9ybXMtb24tc25sLXdpdGgtd29vdHRlby0xMjA4MjQx0gGbAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnBpbmt2aWxsYS5jb20vZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudC9idHMtamluLXNoYXJlcy1iZWhpbmQtdGhlLXNjZW5lcy1vZi10aGUtYXN0cm9uYXV0LXN0YWdlLXdpdGgtY29sZHBsYXktYmFuZC1wZXJmb3Jtcy1vbi1zbmwtd2l0aC13b290dGVvLTEyMDgyNDE_YW1w>
2023-02-08 01:44:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMilwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5waW5rdmlsbGEuY29tL2VudGVydGFpbm1lbnQvYnRzLWppbi1zaGFyZXMtYmVoaW5kLXRoZS1zY2VuZXMtb2YtdGhlLWFzdHJvbmF1dC1zdGFnZS13aXRoLWNvbGRwbGF5LWJhbmQtcGVyZm9ybXMtb24tc25sLXdpdGgtd29vdHRlby0xMjA4MjQx0gGbAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnBpbmt2aWxsYS5jb20vZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudC9idHMtamluLXNoYXJlcy1iZWhpbmQtdGhlLXNjZW5lcy1vZi10aGUtYXN0cm9uYXV0LXN0YWdlLXdpdGgtY29sZHBsYXktYmFuZC1wZXJmb3Jtcy1vbi1zbmwtd2l0aC13b290dGVvLTEyMDgyNDE_YW1w?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en> (referer: None)
2023-02-08 01:44:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMilwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5waW5rdmlsbGEuY29tL2VudGVydGFpbm1lbnQvYnRzLWppbi1zaGFyZXMtYmVoaW5kLXRoZS1zY2VuZXMtb2YtdGhlLWFzdHJvbmF1dC1zdGFnZS13aXRoLWNvbGRwbGF5LWJhbmQtcGVyZm9ybXMtb24tc25sLXdpdGgtd29vdHRlby0xMjA4MjQx0gGbAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnBpbmt2aWxsYS5jb20vZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudC9idHMtamluLXNoYXJlcy1iZWhpbmQtdGhlLXNjZW5lcy1vZi10aGUtYXN0cm9uYXV0LXN0YWdlLXdpdGgtY29sZHBsYXktYmFuZC1wZXJmb3Jtcy1vbi1zbmwtd2l0aC13b290dGVvLTEyMDgyNDE_YW1w?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en>
{'url': 'https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMilwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5waW5rdmlsbGEuY29tL2VudGVydGFpbm1lbnQvYnRzLWppbi1zaGFyZXMtYmVoaW5kLXRoZS1zY2VuZXMtb2YtdGhlLWFzdHJvbmF1dC1zdGFnZS13aXRoLWNvbGRwbGF5LWJhbmQtcGVyZm9ybXMtb24tc25sLXdpdGgtd29vdHRlby0xMjA4MjQx0gGbAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnBpbmt2aWxsYS5jb20vZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudC9idHMtamluLXNoYXJlcy1iZWhpbmQtdGhlLXNjZW5lcy1vZi10aGUtYXN0cm9uYXV0LXN0YWdlLXdpdGgtY29sZHBsYXktYmFuZC1wZXJmb3Jtcy1vbi1zbmwtd2l0aC13b290dGVvLTEyMDgyNDE_YW1w?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en'}
2023-02-08 01:44:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-02-08 01:44:27 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (1 items) in: items.json
2023-02-08 01:44:27 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1561,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 104182,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.162381,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 7, 20, 14, 27, 736096),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 302666,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 7, 20, 14, 26, 573715)}
2023-02-08 01:44:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

item.json

```json
[
{"url": "https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMilwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5waW5rdmlsbGEuY29tL2VudGVydGFpbm1lbnQvYnRzLWppbi1zaGFyZXMtYmVoaW5kLXRoZS1zY2VuZXMtb2YtdGhlLWFzdHJvbmF1dC1zdGFnZS13aXRoLWNvbGRwbGF5LWJhbmQtcGVyZm9ybXMtb24tc25sLXdpdGgtd29vdHRlby0xMjA4MjQx0gGbAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnBpbmt2aWxsYS5jb20vZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudC9idHMtamluLXNoYXJlcy1iZWhpbmQtdGhlLXNjZW5lcy1vZi10aGUtYXN0cm9uYXV0LXN0YWdlLXdpdGgtY29sZHBsYXktYmFuZC1wZXJmb3Jtcy1vbi1zbmwtd2l0aC13b290dGVvLTEyMDgyNDE_YW1w?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en"}
]
```

I expect the url to `https://www.pinkvilla.com/entertainment/bts-jin-shares-behind-the-scenes-of-the-astronaut-stage-with-coldplay-band-performs-on-snl-with-wootteo-1208241`

I've tried setting params such as dont_redirect, handle_httpstatus_list, etc. but nothing working out

What am I missing?
Any guidance would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your missing is that the `302` redirect that you see in your logs is not redirecting to the page you are expecting.  The redirect in your logs is simply taking you from `...news.google.com/rss/articles/CBM...yNDE_YW1w` to `...news.google.com/rss/articles/CBM...yNDE_YW1w?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en`.

The `url` for the page that you are expecting it to redirect to can actually be found in the `html` for the page that it is being directed to.  In fact it is the only link, along with a whole bunch of javascript which facilitates the redirect that happens automatically in your browser.

for example:

```py
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMilwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5waW5rdmlsbGEuY29tL2VudGVydGFpbm1lbnQvYnRzLWppbi1zaGFyZXMtYmVoaW5kLXRoZS1zY2VuZXMtb2YtdGhlLWFzdHJvbmF1dC1zdGFnZS13aXRoLWNvbGRwbGF5LWJhbmQtcGVyZm9ybXMtb24tc25sLXdpdGgtd29vdHRlby0xMjA4MjQx0gGbAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnBpbmt2aWxsYS5jb20vZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudC9idHMtamluLXNoYXJlcy1iZWhpbmQtdGhlLXNjZW5lcy1vZi10aGUtYXN0cm9uYXV0LXN0YWdlLXdpdGgtY29sZHBsYXktYmFuZC1wZXJmb3Jtcy1vbi1zbmwtd2l0aC13b290dGVvLTEyMDgyNDE_YW1w']

    def parse(self, response):

        m = response.xpath("//a/@href").get()  # grab the href for the only link on the page

        yield {"links": m}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2023-02-07 18:39:55 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMilwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5waW5rdmlsbGEuY29tL2VudGVydGFpbm1lbnQvYnRzLWppbi1zaGFyZXMtYmVoaW5kLXRoZS1zY2VuZXMt
b2YtdGhlLWFzdHJvbmF1dC1zdGFnZS13aXRoLWNvbGRwbGF5LWJhbmQtcGVyZm9ybXMtb24tc25sLXdpdGgtd29vdHRlby0xMjA4MjQx0gGbAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnBpbmt2aWxsYS5jb20vZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudC9idHMtamluLXNoYXJlcy1iZWhpbmQtdGhlLXNjZW5lcy1v
Zi10aGUtYXN0cm9uYXV0LXN0YWdlLXdpdGgtY29sZHBsYXktYmFuZC1wZXJmb3Jtcy1vbi1zbmwtd2l0aC13b290dGVvLTEyMDgyNDE_YW1w?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en>


{'links': 'https://www.pinkvilla.com/entertainment/bts-jin-shares-behind-the-scenes-of-the-astronaut-stage-with-coldplay-band-performs-on-snl-with-wootteo-1208241'}


2023-02-07 18:39:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-02-07 18:39:55 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (1 items) in: items.json
2023-02-07 18:39:55 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Since scrapy doesn't execute any of the javascript in the response for the `google.news.com/rss` request the redirect that happens in your browser doesn't get triggered by scrapy.